# Local Job unable to find Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to run an AWS GLUE job locally from a docker container and I am getting the following error:

```
    File "/glue/script.py", line 19, in <module>
        job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
      File "/glue/aws-glue-libs/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/job.py", line 38, in init
      File "/glue/spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
      File "/glue/spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
      File "/glue/spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.init.
    : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load region information from any provider in the chain
```

It appears that its unable to find the region but I have stored my config and credentials files in the usual path within the container so it should be able to find it from there. Or should I be trying to declare the region from within the script file?

Here are the first few lines of the job, it currently fails on the last line:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame## @type: DataSource
import datetime
import boto3

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried running the glue jobs locally from a Docker container and it worked well for me.

I have written a blog around the same and the docker image is also avaliable on dockerhub. Not very sure of this error but if you want to use the image  I am providing the link to the same

Article: https://towardsdatascience.com/develop-glue-jobs-locally-using-docker-containers-bffc9d95bd1

Github: https://github.com/jnshubham/aws-glue-local-etl-docker

I don't face region issue using this, check if this helps you.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response, i have actually followed your tutorial to set everything up and I am using your docker container - not sure why I'm running into problems...

Comment: Can you update the job in your question? and also the spark-submit command you are trying to run

Comment: Once inside the docker container, try setting region export AWS_REGION=us-east-1 and then running your code. I created the image on ec2 instance that's why I didn't faced this issue.

Comment: Hi, that worked perfectly, I also had to set my access key/secret access key/token as environment variables within the container the same way so you may want to add that to your blog post for others. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
[default]
output = json
region = us-east-1
```

Comment: add the above content in under .aws\config file, that should fix your issue ,

Comment: Comments may get deleted at any time - could you add all required information to the post itself rather than using comments